# "Faut pas trop y compter"?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

Came across this sentence in *Astérix* and had no idea what it meant. The main character, Astérix, says "J'aimerais bien une bonne bagarre," and his friend Obélix responds "Faut pas trop y compter."

What does his response mean?

Comment: Good choice of "bandes dessinées" ;)

Comment: Just started the series! There's so many of them though....doubt I'll ever get through them all.

Comment: Yeah right, there are 36 of them. But I think it's worth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Faut pas trop y compter" has a simple correspondence to English:

- "Faut pas" - must not
- "trop" -- too much
- "y" -- may depend on context but in this case, 'on it' or 'on that', i.e. "what you just said"
- "compter" -- count

So "Must not count on it too much".

More idiomatically,

- I'd really like a good fight
- "[you or we] Can't count on that!" or "You'd better not count on that too much", implying, "That good fight you're counting on might not happen"

Comment: Your answer + GAM PUB's answer together give all the info I need, wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 8):

The *y* is for “il y a une bonne bagarre”, the *compter* is “to count on” with the nuance of anticipation, [*prevoir* in french](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/compter).

Therefore : *You should not count on it* (on any good bagarre).

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't follow. Is *faut* short for *Il faut...* ? I don't know what it means at the beginning of a sentence on its own. You've perfectly explained the *y compter*, but I actually don't understand *Faut pas trop* either.

Comment: I would have interpreted your question the same way oldergod did

Comment: @Aerovistae: yes, "faut" is a shortcut of "il faut", here. Happens a lot in spoken french (which the BD (Bande Dessinée) describes) (note: I use "Happens" instead of "It happens", as an illustration of the same kind of shortcuts in English common langage ^^)

Comment: @GAMPUB that makes no sense. There should be no interpreting going on, I asked about one sentence and only half of that sentence was explained. How does it make sense to "interpret" my confusion as only pertaining to the *y compter*?

Comment: @GAMPUB moreover you then went on to answer my question perfectly so I'm especially confused.

Comment: @Aerovistae Sorry, it was the way I understood it as I read it the first time. My bad, then...

Comment: @Aerovistae Sorry, I did not explain the first part of it because it seemed to be it would be something you would know as for (1) the difference of difficulty with the latter part of the sentence is rather large, and (2) that "faut pas" would be something already learned if you were reading something as Asterix. I see you got others answering it for you anyway.

Comment: I do a lot of reading and have very little exposure to casual speech so sometimes I am thrown by oral-style shorthand, like the omission of *il*. I would recognize *y'a* but *faut* was new. I didn't want to assume it was short for *Il ne faut pas* when it might have been some idiom I was unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 6):

*Faut pas trop y compter* is a shortcut for

> Il ne faut pas trop compter là-dessus.

*faut* is third person of the defective verb *falloir*.

This translates:

> One shouldn't count too much on it.

or

> One shouldn't rely too much on it.

Answer (score 6):

So two things in your question:

1. *faut* is a standard truncation for *il faut*, a necessity modality marker; in this context => you shouldn't
2. *y compter* stands for *compter sur ça* => *count on it*

Dropping the impersonal *il* happens with other verbs:

- **faire**: *fait froid*, *fait suer*, ...
- **y avoir**: *y a rien*, *y a pas photo*, ...

But not all, with meteo verbs, it's not common to drop the pronoun:

- *il pleut* => [iplø] but not [plø]