# What does the "y" stand for in "Je m'y attendais"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

What does the "y" stand for in "Je m'y attendais"? There's no À, and it certainly does not mention some place there. So why is there a "Y"?

Comment: Please provide context "Y" is a pronoun and stands for something but we cannot tell you what if you do not say what comes before.

Comment: Could you rephrase that? I couldn't understand

Comment: The answers to [this post](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/16862/358) might help you.

Comment: "Y" stands for something that is mentioned before so you must write more, not just the sentence you do not understand.

Comment: Y stands for *à ça*, i.e. *Je m'attendais à ça*.

Comment: "Je m'y attendais" --> "I was expecting it". Y in french stand for 'it' in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personal pronoun "y" can replace something that is indirect object to a verb whose indirect object is introduced by preposition "à".

**A verb phrase** :

> A- Il pleut.
>   B- Je m'y attendais, il y avait de gros nuages noirs.

**A noun** :

> A- Voilà la pluie.
>   B- Je m'y attendais, il y avait de gros nuages noirs.

The verb is "*s'attendre à*". We could react to "*Il pleut*" with:

> Je m'attendais à ce qu'il pleuve.

and to "*Voilà la pluie*" with :

> Je m'attendais à la pluie.

we will usually replace "à ce qu'il pleuve" or "à la pluie" by personal pronoun "y" placed just before the verb.

Comment: *y* can replace more than just verb phrases.

Comment: Obviously. And this is not a complete grammar course about the use of "y". This is an answer to OP's question.

Comment: That may be true, but how can you be sure it replaced a verb phrase in this case without the OP having given context?

Comment: @Sander Read Laure's reply closer, she wrote "can replace" not "does replace".

Comment: @jlliagre I am aware of that. What I'm just trying to say is that, though it is a completely correct answer, it might give the OP the impression that a verb phrase is the only thing *y* could have replaced in this sentence.

Comment: @Sander Point taken, I'll expand a little.

Comment: The personal pronoun Y. I think if you're giving grammar explanations, your grammar should be right....

Comment: @Lambie: Just fix it if you're bothered. English grammar is not the topic here.

Comment: Am I the only one who think *y avoir* (as presented in *il y avait*) is different from other uses of *y*?